# PHP - How to array push inside a json array

Tags: php, arrays, json

Here Am trying to insert a field inside a json array

```
 "filterField": [
                {
                    "fieldName": "Tray",
                    "fieldId": 10
                },
                {
                    "fieldName": "Tray",
                    "fieldId": 10
                },
```

This is my json array inside object `$brand[];`
am trying to put a additional fields
the result I want is

```
"filterField": [
                {
                    "fieldName": "Tray",
                    "fieldId": 10,
                    "newField":20
                },
                {
                    "fieldName": "Tray",
                    "fieldId": 10,
                    "newField":20
                },
```

I tried it like this way

```
$arr = array();
foreach ($brand as $BrValue) {
    $arr[] = array_push($BrValue, array('newField' => 20));
}
print_r($arr);
```

Where am doing wrong. Can I get help? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't use `array_push()` to add to an associative array, you just assign to the new key.

```
$arr = [];
foreach ($brand as $BrValue) {
    $BrValue['newField'] = 20;
    $arr[] = $BrValue;
}
```

If you want to modify the original `$brand` array, you can use a reference variable instead of pushing the elements onto a new array.

```
foreach ($brand as &$BrValue) {
    $BrValue['newField'] = 20;
}
```